# Fashion Design questions appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, support

I wonder whether there is any place here in stack exchange where one can discuss fashion design (fashion of things you wear, clothes, apparel, etc.).

Is the graphic design site appropriate for this, and, if so, what tags are available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the question. Generally no its not appropriate. But uf you were to ask about how to draw a repeat for print or weaving that might be acceptable. While asking about changes needed to make to a pattern to fit a human of a difference size is not.